# C# и работа с Drive API

Tags: c#, google-drive

Как отправить `.zip`-архив в облако, и какие есть варианты типов файлов в *MimeType* кроме `text/plain`?

Answer (score 2):

> какие есть варианты типов файлов в MimeType кроме text/plain

[Список MIME-типов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_MIME-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Answer (score 2):

Вот [официальный пример](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert):

```
Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File insertFile(
    DriveService service,
    string title, string description,
    string parentId, string mimeType,
    string filename)
{
    var fileDesc = new Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File()
    {
        Title = title, 
        Description = description,
        MimeType = mimeType,
        // устанавливаем каталог
        Parents = string.IsNullOrEmpty(parentId) ? null :
            new List<ParentReference>()
            {
                new ParentReference() { Id = parentId }
            }
    }

    using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filename))
    {
        var request = service.Files.Insert(body, stream, mimeType);
        request.Upload();
        return request.ResponseBody;
    }
    // может быть выброшено исключение
}
```

Более полный пример [здесь](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-cs).

---

Mime-тип для zip-файла — application/zip (или просто application/octet-stream).